# Flink IOException: Insufficient number of network buffers

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using `Flink v1.4.0`. I am using the `DataSet API` (though this, I don't think matters).

I am running some heavy duty transformations on a 12 core VM. I am utilising 2 cores for one `Flink job` in which I am storing some data into a `Flink Queryable State`and am running another `Flink` job with the remaining 10 cores.

When I run the second job with 10 cores I seem to get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Insufficient number of network buffers: required 10, but only 9 available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 4096 of 32768 bytes each. You can increase this number by setting the configuration keys 'taskmanager.network.memory.fraction', 'taskmanager.network.memory.min', and 'taskmanager.network.memory.max'.
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool.createBufferPool(NetworkBufferPool.java:257)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NetworkEnvironment.registerTask(NetworkEnvironment.java:199)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:618)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I do run it with 8 cores it makes it through just fine. What's causing this and why can't I use the other 2 --> 8+2 = 10 cores?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting the Apache Flink FAQ:

> If you run Flink with a very high parallelism, you may need to increase the number of network buffers.
>
> By default, Flink takes 10% of the JVM heap size for network buffers, with a minimum of 64MB and a maximum of 1GB. You can adjust all these values via taskmanager.network.memory.fraction, taskmanager.network.memory.min, and taskmanager.network.memory.max.
>
> Please refer to the Configuration Reference for details.

There is a [dedicated section in the docs for how to configure the network buffers](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/config.html#configuring-the-network-buffers).

In summary, you can configure the number of network buffers in the `./conf/flink-conf.yaml` file by setting the `taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers` parameter.

The parameter should be set to `#slots-per-TM^2 * #TMs * 4`, where `#slots per TM` are the number of slots per TaskManager and `#TMs` are the total number of task managers.

To support, for example, a cluster of 20 8-slot machines, you should use roughly 5000 network buffers for optimal throughput. Each network buffer has by default a size of 32 KiBytes. In the example above, the system would thus allocate roughly 300 MiBytes for network buffers.

Please refer to the docs for details.

Comment: I fixed this, but the problem remains when I run Flink from IntelliJ. I am actually getting a very similar one, this one though refers me to the configuration keys 'taskmanager.network.memory.fraction', 'taskmanager.network.memory.min', and 'taskmanager.network.memory.max'. In general, is there a way to pass this arguments to Flink from IntelliJ or through the Flink execution environment?

Comment: The formula you gave can be at best a rough estimate. It doesn't account for the size of the processing graph at all.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same error

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insufficient number of network
> buffers: required 13, but only 7 available. The total number of
> network buffers is currently set to 2048 of 32768 bytes each. You can
> increase this number by setting the configuration keys
> 'taskmanager.memory.network.fraction',
> 'taskmanager.memory.network.min', and
> 'taskmanager.memory.network.max'.

The below code snippet resolved my issue.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
int defaultLocalParallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
cfg.setString("taskmanager.memory.network.max", "1gb");
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(defaultLocalParallelism, cfg);
```